# Making sense of covariance of space-time white noise as a product of delta distributions

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, distribution-theory, covariance

The covariance of space-time white noise $\dot{W}(x,t)$ is given by $\mathbb{E}\dot{W}(x,t)\dot{W}(y,s) = \delta(t-s)\delta(x-y)$, where the $\delta$-distribution satisfies $\delta(x) = 0$ if $x\neq 0$ and $\delta(x) = \infty$ if $x = 0$.  What I don't get is, isn't the product of distributions undefined first of all? And also, what if $t=s$ but $y\neq x$ above? Then you'd get $0\times\infty$.  What to do then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can multiply distributions when they contain different sets of variables.
This operation is called the tensor product of distributions. One can also invertible do a linear change of variables inside distributions.

Comment: oh okay, so is there some way to make sense of what the $0\times\infty$ might be in this case?

Comment: Not really. The point of distributions is you can't in general evaluate them at points but you have to smear and average. Take $\delta(x)\delta(y)$ which is a well defined distribution on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Its singular support is the origin which means essentially that you are only able to evaluate that pointwise for $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$. In which case the value is zero. So one could perhaps say between lots of quotes, one can plug $(x,y)=(1,0)$ and get $0\times\infty=0$ in some sense. I would not put too much stock in this kind of heuristic calculation though.

Comment: Ah I see, so when papers mention that as the covariance, they're not meant to be taken super literally? just like a heuristic

Comment: The covariances are to be taken seriously. They are well defined rigorous mathematical objects. However these are Schwartz distributions aka generalized functions. What is not to be taken too seriously is the writing of these as if they were ordinary functions. In order to better understand the subject you have go through a bit of theory of distributions. A good intro is the book by Strichartz.

Comment: Ohh so the covariance itself is thought of as a distribution, thanks for the book reccommendation